# Android Realm - Primary Key Constraint Exception & Duplication

Tags: android, primary-key, realm

I'm new to Android programming and Realm. Couldn't find any related articles so I'm posting the question here..

I'm writing to Realm from my JSONfile, which is recorded and reflected in the RealmBrowser. But when I restart my app, I'm getting error on `io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 20151101`. All values are derived directly from my JSON file and I run it in a for loop under all data has been recorded in the Realm database.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonFile.length(); i++) {
try {

  RealmConfiguration objectDB = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getContext()).
                                name("objectDB.realm").build();
  Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(objectDB);
  realm.beginTransaction();

  Object object = realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Object.class, jsonFile);
  object.setPrimaryId(primaryId);

  //and set more more data...

  realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(object);
  realm.commitTransaction();

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

My understanding is that if the primaryKey exists on the Realm table, it will only update changes to any of the setters(), but now I'm having "io.realm.internal.Table.throwDuplicatePrimaryKeyException" error. Can anyone advise where or what I have done wrong along the way?

Many thanks to the kind folks here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace this

```
 Object object = realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Object.class, jsonFile);
 object.setPrimaryId(primaryId);

 //and set more more data...

 realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(object);
```

With something like this

```
 Object object = gson.fromJson(jsonFile, Object.class);
 object.setPrimaryId(primaryId);
 realm.beginTransaction();
 realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(object);
 realm.commitTransaction();
```

Gson is a dependency of Realm, so I think you can just do `Gson gson = new Gson()` somewhere to make one.

Comment: Yes, that should work, just be aware that GSON requires a special setup when used with Realm https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#gson

Comment: using gson solves the primaryKey issue, but increased the loading time by 6fold. It also seems like gson have a different way to handle multi-relations between RealmObjects/RealmList..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this line?

```
 object.setPrimaryId(primaryId);
```

I would assume that information would be part of the jsonFile, and the primary key you set there probably conflicts with one that already exists.

Comment: I was required to declare the primaryKey during compilation, otherwise it keeps throwing error that I didn't have a primaryKey. My jsonFile looks something like
{"20151101": { values},
 "20151102": {values}}.... hence I'm using the object as the primaryKey identifier.

Comment: if there is an change to the content under the same primaryKey, how can it be done?

Comment: Ah, it is because your primary key isn't actually _in_ the JSON it is the key? Your approach will probably work the first time, but not the 2nd. The reason is that calling `createOrUpdateObject` will give it an implicit key of `0`. Setting the primary key right after will check if it already exists (which it does the 2nd time around) and throw an error. You only choice is either to format your JSON so it matches the RealmObject or use a JSON mapper like GSON first. Sorry.

Comment: you are right mate! 1st time works fine but 2nd crashes.. Regarding GSON, it is able to write into the realmDB if its a JSONObject. However if it contains a JSONArray of values, following Realm's documentation on creating multi-relations "many-to-many", GSON will produces null pointer error when I try to write a nested RealmList<SubObject> within the first RealmObject. Error occurs when I write the following `FirstObject.getSubObjectValue().add(value)`. Are there changes to the way of writing it when I use the GSON lib?

Comment: Please ignore the earlier question.. I just found from the documentation that Realm at the moment doesn't support Primitive lists for GSON, which probably explains why I'm seeing the null pointer exception.